# JSP Buffer overflow

Tags: jsp, buffer-overflow

I have a 1MB file to upload and the following is set and I get an exception.  I think it is my buffer size and or the autoFlush setting.

currently:

```
<%@ page errorPage="error.jsp" buffer="500kb" autoFlush="false" %>
```

I tried to set the buffer to 2000KB but no luk.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the exception & trace.

Comment: Once I updated the Buffer size and copied it out to the testing server.  Somehow I forgot to clear the cache out so it was running the old version.  Once I did a clean compile/release and restarted the site and cleared the cache it worked.  IT was just the buffer size I needed to up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the buffer for *output*, but a file upload is *input*.

The solution depends on your web framework.

Comment: Actually I guess I said it wrong.  The file uploads ok.  But when I uncomment the code to display the results in a grid it errors out.  So I assume it is doing with the output.  Does that makes sense?  Thanks